# Python - Prime Number exercise

Tags: python

Note, this is not my homework assignment! I'm just trying to understand Python (and math, sadly) at the same time. I know the ultimate goal of this program is to get a list of prime numbers in the range 1 to 20, however, once it gets to the "for x in range..." line, I'm getting lost and the tutorial doesn't explain it in detail.

Could you please explain in plain English step by step and clarify specifically

a) what is x in the line `for x in range (2,n)`

b) in the line `for x in range (2,n),` what is `n`? Is it the same "n" at the bottom?

c) what is this `n, x, n // x` saying exactly. Please clarify the `//`

thanks if you can help

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        print("1 is special")
        return False
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print("{} equals {} x {}".format(n, x, n // x))
            return False
    else:
        print(n, "is a prime number")
        return True

for n in range(1, 20):
    isprime(n)
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is a REALLY grossly inefficient algorithm. Much better to change the range line to `for x in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2)`. You'll need to `import math` and add another special case on 2. This dramatically decreases the number of checks that must be done. There's no point in checking past sqrt+1 because past there you'll only find inverses (e.g. 5 x 2 instead of 2 x 5). Special casing 2 cuts the number of checks in half. Checking 611953 for instance, the reduces the number of checks 780-fold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a)

```
for x in range (2,n)
```

is the same like

```
for (x = 2; x < n; x++)
```

in some other language: a loop where x gets integer values between 2 and n-1 included.

b)

```
for x in range (2,n):
```

this `n` comes from the first `def isprime(n)` and is whatever this function is later called with. In this case it is always the same `n` from the bottom.

c)

```
print("{} equals {} x {}".format(n, x, n // x))
```

this writes the following text: `A equals B x C` where `A` is `n`, `B` is `x` and `C` is `n/x` rounded to the nearest smaller integer. It is so called integer division (e.g. `9 // 2 = 4`)

Answer (score 3):

a) Try this at the prompt:

```
help(range)
```

It will tell you that range(a,b) returns a list atarting as a, ending at b-1, so

```
range(2,10)
```

is

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Play at the prompt, type `range(2,2)`, `range(2,-1)`, `range(2,3)` and see what comes out. You'll see that n==1 isn't the only special case.

Now, something like `for x in y` iterates over the elements of y, which in your case would be a list. You can also verify this at the prompt:

```
for x in range(2,10) :
    print x
```

b) the block starting with `def isprime(n)` is a function, with argument n. You can call it for any n: `isprime(100)`. At the bottom of the code, you are iterating over `range(1,20)` (if in doubt type it into the prompt) and calling isprime for each value, i.e. 1,2,3,4,...,19.

Note that in this example, there isn't a need to create and return a list with `range`, you can use `xrange`, which is a generator. Type help(xrange) in the prompt...

Comment: thanks, I'm very new to Python. Can you explain what the prompt is and how to use it?

Comment: @Michael seriously? Just type `python`.

Comment: @Michael on Linux, Unix, MacOSX you just type python. No idea what you do on windows but I suspect google will know. Now, apart from the coding side of things, you may want to consider more efficient algorithms for this problem, see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @Michael: "trying to understand Python" without reading http://docs.python.org/tutorial/ first is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Michael, Wooble is right, the tutorial is very good. And in python you can figure out a lot of things by playing around at the prompt, so it is easy to learn faster than with other languages.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman @juanchopanza  yes, serious. I'm totally new to programming. I have python installed in the text editor (Eclipse) so I don't think typing "Python" from the command line will automatically access the files that are in the text editor

Comment: @Michael it's nothing to do with files in your text editor. You use the Python shell to experiment with syntax and explore objects' properties, as juanchopanza recommends with his `help` tip above.

Comment: @Michael Eclipse is not an editor, it is a so-called IDE. But whatever it is, you should be able to find out where your files are. But I suspect the python Eclipse view has a python console into which you can type commands. But for learning and playing around you don't even need your files, just a terminal.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman @juanchopanza o.k., thanks, I tried it. I thought to do help(range) you were telling me to test the code in that specific file. I see now that it gives me general info back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a) x takes on the values from `2` to `n-1` (since `range` excludes the upper bound)

b) No, it's the same `n` as in the method definition (i.e. the method argument)

c) Integer division