# Python: Prime numbers and the in range()

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, iteration

I am learning python and  was looking at this problem:
[Python - Prime Number exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566807/python-prime-number-exercise)
Here are my questions:
When n=2, the range will  be (2,n), in the other words the range is between 2 and 2-1=1.

```
   for x in range(2, n):
      if n % x == 0:
        print("{} equals {} x {}".format(n, x, n // x))
        return False
   else:
      print(n, "is a prime number")
      return True
```

a. Will it be 2%2?

b. If the number is even, it will print

> A equals B x C

will the loop break once the condition is true or it will finish the loop?

c. is the else outside the loop? what if statement does it correspond? (i know it is the  `if n % x == 0:`) but howcome it is seems like it is outside the loop?
I tried to run it, and understand, but then I got confused.

Comment: Please, correct formatting of your code, it is important. I guess, the `else` shall be on the same level as `for`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## for .. else confusion

You seem to be confused by `else` which is part of the `for` loop.

You are not the only one.

In Python, `for` loop might have at the end `else` section, which is executed after all the loops are finished, unless there was `break` statement. Yes, it is not very intuitive.

So you shall read the `else` section as last part of the `for` loop.

```
def looptest(loops=5):
    for i in range(loops):
        print "i", i
        if i == 3:
            print "in if"
            return
    else:    
        print "in else of the loop"
```

and try it for loops == 5:

```
>>> looptest(5)
i 0
i 1
i 2
i 3
in if
```

For number of loops 2 we do not expect return, we shall run through `else` of the loop:

```
>>> looptest(2)
i 0
i 1
in else of the loop
```

Note, that `return` must be within function, trying return on console would result in error.

## range(2, 2) == []

Trying on Python console:

```
>>> range(2, 2)
[]
```

## return

return ends up current function or run in the whole module. So after `return`, no further code in the same part of your code is executed (with exceptions like `try`, `finally`, context managers etc, but this is not relevant to your code).

Comment: How about the range? and I am confused with the return statement.

Comment: According to this website: [link]( https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html) , "the else clause belongs to the for loop, not the if statement"

Comment: @eLg: this is exactly what I was trying to describe. Do you think, I did describe it differently or you are only confirming understanding?

Comment: confirming... so what will happen to the if condition if it is true? if the condition is false and the loop is not yet finished, should it print n is a prime number many times until the loop is done?

Comment: @eLg: if the condition in `if` is true, code enter the inner block of `if` from where it `returns`, so the code will not have any chance to run within `else` related to `for` loop. Here you shall consider `return` being the same as `break` (only a bit more brutal).

Answer (score 1):

a. No. `range(2,2)`is an empty set in Python.

b. As soon as the condition is true, the function that contains the loop will return, and the loop will not finish.  That's because the `return` call is one level down from the `if` statement.

c. I'm pretty sure you want the `else` to correspond with the `for`.  Python's got this for...else syntax that executes the content of the `else` clause if the `for` loop terminates normally (i.e. without a `break`).

In other words, I think you want this:

```
for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print("{} equals {} x {}".format(n, x, n // x))
            return False
else:
     print(n, "is a prime number")
     return True
```

EDIT:

Sure, I can explain the whole loop.  The idea is this: for each number between two and n, check if that number is a factor of x.  If it is, then n isn't prime, and we kill the loop.  However, if we make it all the way to the end of the loop, we know that n is prime, because it has no factors between 2 and n.  The else clause then kicks in, and prints that the number is prime.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this function:

```
def isPrime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1):
        if n % i ==0:
            return False
    return True
```

Iterating through every possible option isn't necessarily the best option; keep in mind the range will never be more than the square root of the number.

Also worth noting, your output will only print the first set of factors.

Comment: I am confused with the return True, and return False

Comment: so our for loop checks each number between 2 and the sqrt of our number. The False exits 'early' if you will; as soon as a factor is found saying 'This number has factors!'; if the for loop finishes and never found a factor the function returns True saying 'This is a prime number!'

Comment: I just want to verify. if the if condition is true, it will return false and the loop will break/exit/stop. if the condition is false, it will return true and the loop will continue.

Comment: You've got that backwards the condition you're checking is whether a number is prime. If a number is divisible by any numbers other than 1, Num it is NOT PRIME, return False and stop trying. If it has tried every possible whole divisor it is PRIME, return True.

Comment: Scratch that, what you said is valid if the condition you're referring is n % i == 0