# Prime checker not eliminating numbers divisible by 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program looks at an input and then return a list of all prime numbers less than or equal to the number.  It currently is not eliminating numbers divisible by 5, and my 'Testing divisibility by' statement is returning 3 each time.

```
import math


def is_prime(number):
    if number % 2:
        # equivalent to if number % 2 != 0 because if number is
        # divisible by 2 it will return 0, evaluating as 'False'.
        for num in range(3, int(math.sqrt(number)) + 1, 2):
            print("Testing divisibility by {}".format(num))
            if number % num == 0:
               return False
            else:
                return True
    else:
        return False



def list_of_primes(number):
    prime_list = []
    for x in range(2, number + 1):
            if is_prime(x):
                prime_list.append(x)
    return prime_list



def main():
    while True:
        usr_in = eval(input("Please enter a positive number"
                            " greater than 1: "))
        if usr_in > 1: break
        else:
            print("Number not valid.")


    prime_list = list_of_primes(usr_in)
    for x in prime_list:
        print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the if-else within your for-loop:

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number % 2:
        for num in range(3, int(math.sqrt(number)) + 1, 2):
            print("Testing divisibility by {}".format(num))
            if number % num == 0:
               return False
            else:
                return True
    else:
        return False
```

Consider the case when `number` is `25`. In the first iteration of your for-loop, `num` is `3`. Then, since `number%num` (i.e. `25%3`) is not `0`, `False` is not returned, and the `else` is entered and `True` is returned.

This is what you want to do instead (notice there's no `else` in the for-loop):

```
import math


def is_prime(number):
    if number % 2:
        # equivalent to if number % 2 != 0 because if number is
        # divisible by 2 it will return 0, evaluating as 'False'.
        for num in range(3, int(math.sqrt(number)) + 1, 2):
            print("Testing divisibility by {}".format(num))
            if number % num == 0:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your "is_prime" and "list_of_primes" and replace with these:

```
def list_of_nonprimes(number):
    return [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, number, i)]

def list_of_primes(number):
    noprimes = list_of_nonprimes(number)
    return [x for x in range(2, number) if x not in noprimes]
```

... which, by the way, I got from a [List Comprehension Tutorial](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php). Also, I don't think you need to import math in Python 3.4+.

Please refer to this post for a [very nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395201/python-prime-numbers-and-the-in-range?rq=1) of how this works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks like a homework question. In this case, an answer that just says "throw out your code and do this", without explanation, is not helpful. Also, I have Python3.4 here and still have to `import math`.

Comment: Using the above, I did not import math, and I'm using 3.4.

Comment: OP imported math because he used `math.sqrt`. You didn't, and that was why you didn't have to import it.

Comment: So... you're taking the part about "still have to use import math"?